# How to troubleshoot attribution issues on websites when sample URLs are given?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, utm, attribution

So the issue is :
Custom Campaign traffic attribution is not working on  GA4 properties.  UTM parameters like aff code, etc,.. are not getting grouped under affiliate channels.

Because of this, we are not able to measure the affiliate traffic and we already lost almost 2 months of data.
So they have provided us with the sample urls to investigate..
But we dont know the route map to solve this.
Can someone please guide?
Thanks in advance!

Basically we do not the route map for analysing this, a proper guidance on what exactly to be checked, seen, analysed would help us give some light on this problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you know how URLs are routed to code on your own website?  Or why would you not be able to figure it out by examining your code and configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure that this can be answered from the information you gave.  There are a lot of ways to do URL routing, too many to list all of them here.  It depends on which web servers, CDNs, load balancers, languages, and frameworks you are using.

Comment: Currently its just an investigation issue, so can u guide us in how to check it in google analytics?

Comment: Your question needs to be rewritten. It's not clear what help you need, it's also not clear what you call a route map or why you need it if you have sample urls for testing. Why you can't just use the urls, and see how you report the utm params on those pages. Two months without tracking affiliate traffic sounds like someone forgot to hire a technical analyst to set up tracking in GTM/GA. Or they just decided to ask their SEO to do that. Because why not? It's Google, right? No, not right...